# How to programmatically click on a div that has tabindex, onclick and id as attributes

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById("-1").click()
```

```html
 <div tabindex="-1" id="-1" onclick="console.log('yes1')"></div>
```

Somehow `document.getElementById("-1").click()` throws the error Cannot read property 'click' of null.

Please help.

Comment: I've edited your post to include a snippet of your code and it works.

Comment: Is that ID unique in the page DOM?

Comment: Use valid Identifiers see [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: <div ng-repeat="x in categories  | limitTo:7" tabindex="{{(-1)*x.order_num}}" id="{{(-1)*x.order_num}}" ng-click=" read_products(x)" onclick="console.log('yes1');"> the html actually looks like this. when page is ran. i inspected the elements and the correct ids are set. but it still throws the error

Answer (score 1):

Your code works. Try to see where do you use `click()` function and see if they throw an error or not.

```js
document.getElementById("-1").click();
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1" id="-1" onclick="console.log('yes1')"></div>
```